# Create different classes in Foreach loop using MVC5

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, carousel

I am creating a carousel using jQuery and have found some very simple code to implement it if you are coding each image in individually, however I am trying to do it using a foreach loop. The problem is, the first div in the carousel needs the class "item-active" and the rest need the class "item" (see: http://www.bootply.com/94444)

This is where I'm at so far:

```
<div class="row" style="background-color: #dfdfdf; padding-top: 50px;">

    @if (Model.CDSContent != null) { foreach (var item in Model.CDSContent) {
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <a href="/service/@item[" ceid "]"><img src="@Html.Raw(item[" serviceimage "])" class="img-responsive"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    } }

</div>
```

Just not too sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways that you could do that.

1. Use a for loop instead
2. Set a Boolean flag
3. Use Linq to get the list.First() and then foreach over list.Skip(1)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `for` loop, instead of a `foreach` loop. Something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < Model.CDSContent.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                        <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <div class="col-md-4"><a href="/service/@Model.CDSContent.ElementAt(i)["ceid"]"><img src="@Html.Raw(Model.CDSContent.ElementAt(i)["serviceimage"])" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                }
```

And then simply use an `if` statement to check if `i==0` (if it's the first item in the loop), if it is then set its class to item active, if not, set its class to item:

```
@if(i == 0)
{
        <div class="item active">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                   <a href="/service/@Model.CDSContent.ElementAt(i)["ceid"]"><img src="@Html.Raw(Model.CDSContent.ElementAt(i)["serviceimage"])" class="img-responsive"></a>
              </div>
        </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="item">
          <div class="col-md-4">
               <a href="/service/@Model.CDSContent.ElementAt(i)["ceid"]"><img src="@Html.Raw(Model.CDSContent.ElementAt(i)["serviceimage"])" class="img-responsive"></a>
          </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Do I put the if statement inside of the for loop? Anywhere else I put, I receive an error from Visual Studio, so I put it inside the loop and it still doesn't display correctly.

Comment: Yes, you have to put it inside of the `for` loop. And I am not really sure why it still isn't displaying correctly. Your code should look something like this: http://pastebin.com/AQxawFiD

Comment: Thanks for that example. I see where I was putting it in the wrong spot. It is starting to look a little closer now, however it doesn't actually display the images using @Html.Raw(Model.CDSContent.ElementAt(i)["serviceimage"]), yet it was displaying them fine using @Html.Raw(item["serviceimage"]). What is the difference between the two? (Sorry, I am quite novice with this)

Comment: There is not a big difference between them. In the `foreach` loop you're accessing your objects directly, whereas in the `for` loop you're accessing the index, or the position of your elements. So `Model.CDSContent.ElementAt(i)` can actually translate to: give me the element on the "i" position. And I am not quite sure what are you trying to achieve with the `item["serviceimage"]`

Comment: Alright. Do you know why the images wouldn't be showing now?

Answer (score 0):

Just this must be enough;

write **@(item.Equals(Model.CDSContent.First())?"active":"")** instead of **active**

```
   ...
      <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item @(item.Equals(Model.CDSContent.First())?"active":"")">
                    ....
```